# I have a message "DevTools was disconnected from the page" after loading a PCD model

Tags: node.js, three.js, large-data, point-clouds

I've noticed similar issues with the message about DevTools. However, it happened to me  after loading a point-cloud model that consists of about 17 millions of points.
This message didn't appear anymore after optimizing a model to 336'260 points.

What is the maximum size of the model that can be loaded and visualized in three.js or is there any tool or method that support large data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you chewed through your tabs allocated ram. If dev tools is telling you it's disconnected then that's probably what happened.

Comment: Try opening chrome's task manager, then load the large asset again, check how much RAM it's chewing, then edit your code so that it creates a typedArray as soon as the page loads with the siz (in kilobytes) of the file, preferably bigger than the file. This might still break you page, but worth trying if you have a couple of minutes to spare

Comment: Thank you very much!

The problem is that I don't know how to do that. Could you provide an example please?

Comment: this will probably lock your tab up for a while, I'm sorry. Press CTRL+SHIFT+J to open up the browser console. And type in this `var typedArr = new Uint8Array((new Array(1024 * 1024 * 100)).fill(1));`, press enter and your browser should allocate more memory to your tab granted that you've already gone beyond the limit. I don't know what the limit is. Oh and if the tab crashes report this as a bug on crbug.com

Comment: What you should do is find out how big the file is and then replace the 100 with the size. So let's say the file was 256 MB then where you see the funny numbers just replace `100` with `256`. If it's a GB then I can't help you here

Comment: I can verify that this works, tested it with a 10 MB increase of memory and then followed that with another 10MB and could see the difference in browser.

Comment: Thank you so much!
However, I'm probably doing something wrong because nothing happens when I type and press enter.

Comment: Yes, you are right, mainly because the typed array has been created, so what you should do is add that code at the beginning of your code and then load the large file. See the code I shared before forces the browser to give you the amount of RAM you need. Though I do have to warn you, this will be a problem if someone has too many programs running and they open your tab.